# Global geometry of discriminant locus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fibration

Let $X$ be a smooth projective threefold, and $\pi : X \to S$ an elliptic fibration over a surface (i.e. flat, with general fiber an elliptic curve).  I'm interested in constructing such fibrations where $S$ is given and we prescribe the discriminant locus $\Delta \subset S$ of singular fibers.  Are there any sorts of constraints on the possible geometry of the discriminant locus $\Delta \subset S$?  I'm especially interested in situations where $\Delta$ is a union of contractible curves.

A couple more precise questions:

- Can the discriminant locus be a disjoint union of $(-1)$-curves?
- Can $S$ be a Kummer surface, and $\Delta$ the union of the $(-2)$-curves?
- Would the answers change if I additionally insist on isotriviality of $\pi$?

My gut feeling is that not too much can be said, but I don't have a good feel for how to cook up examples.  What would be a good reference to start with?

Comment: This is a very good question, why has no one addressed this?